# how choice when useEffect is executed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I try to understand how `useEffect()` work in React, and why is executed in the last not in the order of my code. This issue causes a problem in my bigger program. My question : There is a possibility to choice when this one is executed ?

log of the console, like you see, is not of the order of print :(

```
0 children null App.js:11:10
2 children null App.js:16:10
1 children 
Array [ "truc" ]
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cookies-yvq16?file=/src/App.js

I make this snippet code to explain my problem

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
let list = [];
function Buffer() {
  let init = null;
  list.push(init);
  return <Comp>{list[0]}</Comp>;
}

function Comp({ children }) {
  console.log("0 children", children);
  useEffect(() => {
    children = ["truc"];
    console.log("1 children", children);
  }, []);
  console.log("2 children", children);
  return <div>Super Buffer</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Buffer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` runs after the render.

Comment: If you want to run something after render page, then you can use `useEffect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is executed in the last not in the order of my code.

Because that's its purpose, that's what it's for. From the documentation:

> **`useEffect`**
>
> `useEffect(didUpdate);`
>
> Accepts a function that contains imperative, possibly effectful code.
>
> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and inconsistencies in the UI.
>
> Instead, use `useEffect`. The function passed to `useEffect` will run after the render is committed to the screen. Think of effects as an escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative world.

This article by Dan Abramov may also be useful: [*A Complete Guide to useEffect*](https://amiiy.github.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/). Despite the title, it doesn't just cover `useEffect`, but the whole way hooks and function components work.

> There is a possibility to choice when this one is executed ?

It's not really clear from your question what you want to do instead, but if you want to do something right away, just do it right away without any wrapper function. But remember that your component function runs every time the component needs to re-render, so `useEffect` is what you use to run things only A) When the component first mounts (and optionally when it unmounts) or B) When certain things change.

> ```
> children = ["truc"];
> ```

That's very suspect code, since `children` is a prop. You shouldn't be assigning to props (not even destructured copies of them). Props are state controlled by the parent component. The component should only use them, not try to directly modify them.

Comment: thx for your light, I'm going to read your link. if that's can help help a link to the main program: https://github.com/StanLepunK/gatsby_react_lab/blob/main/src/components/p5_wrapper.js

Comment: Now I understand, well. Now I think I must change my code to keep the data store in my array for the next round...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps, render takes place from children to parent components. In case you need to handle some execution in the order wanted, you can use the parent's `useEffect` like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
let list = [];
function Buffer() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("2 children", list[0]); //log moved here
  }, []);
  let init = null;
  let children = list.push(init);
  return <Comp>{list[0]}</Comp>;
}

function Comp({ children }) {
  console.log("0 children", children);
  useEffect(() => {
    children = ["truc"];
    console.log("1 children", children);
  }, []);

  return <div>Super Buffer</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Buffer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

OutPut:

```
0 children null
1 children (1) ["truc"]
2 children null
```

To log the children in the parent you would need to define the children variable in the parent and wont need to pass that down the prop, for this sample case at least

Comment: thx for thge trick. I need a refactor my code to see my problem stay or go away !!!

Answer (score 0):

your useEffect() has a dependency array which specifies when to rerender

it is the empty array in your code. When it is empty, it only renders once your compnent renders. If you want to make it render when something changes, you need this dependency inside of that array

```
  useEffect(() => {
    children = ["truc"];
    console.log("1 children", children);
  }, [children]);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: whatever you put in the dependency array `useEffect()` will run after the render and produce the same output the OP is describing as a problem.