# How use useEffect correctly with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect

like I post here :   [how choice when useEffect is executed in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544575/how-choice-when-useeffect-is-executed-in-react) I want use `useEffect()` with an array must be store to reuse after. But I cannot figure how to do that in React. I try to make my problem as clear as possible.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
let list = [];
function Buffer(props) {
  let init = null;
  if (list.length === 0) {
    console.log("only once go here and that what I want !!!");
    list.push(init);
  }
  return <Comp title={props.title}>{list[0]}</Comp>;
}

function Comp({ children, ...props }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    children = ["truc"];
    console.log(props.title, "Comp + useEffect():", children);
  }, []);
  console.log(props.title, "Comp:", children);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title} + {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Buffer title="step 0" />
      <Buffer title="step 1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

NIGHTMARE : output
bellow my dream...

```
only once go here and that what I want !!! index.js:27:25
step 0 Comp: null index.js:27:25
step 1 Comp: null index.js:27:25
step 0 Comp + useEffect(): 
Array [ "truc" ]
index.js:27:25
step 1 Comp + useEffect(): 
Array [ "truc" ]
```

DREAM  : output
my output goal in my dream is
the step 1, keep the the `truc`and must not `null`, it's here where my dream became a nightmare.

```
only once go here and that what I want !!! index.js:27:25
step 0 Comp: null index.js:27:25
step 1 Comp: Array [ "truc" ] index.js:27:25
step 0 Comp + useEffect(): 
Array [ "truc" ]
index.js:27:25
step 1 Comp + useEffect(): 
Array [ "truc" ]
```

the snippet in action https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cookies-yvq16?file=/src/App.js:0-716

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but a mistake you are making is manipulating the props. Any type of prop shouldn't be modified directly, use state variables instead. Also, when rendering more than one element of the same type, they must have a prop to uniquely identify each one of them.

In the given sandbox, I have made these changes. Check it out. Hopefully, it will help.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-shaw-drt4u?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: How is it possible that, in your Sandbox, "step 1" sees the array initialized BEFORE useEffect() of "step 0" is fired and physically set it??? O_O I would have understood step 0 > step 0 useEffect > step 1 (with desired value) > step 1 useEffect

Comment: thx for your answer, but I think is not what i want. In my idea my second `<Buffer/>` must use the content of the array initialize by the the first `<Buffer/>` Sorry if my example is not really easy.